# adding SSL to microchip Generic TCP server application

Tags: ssl, tcp, microchip

Has anybody upgraded the code of generic tcp server application provided by Microchip to SSL?

I added new listener port to existing server socket. But then also its not TCPPutIsReady state. When I tried to connect through ssh client Tera Term its asking for username and password. But does it required for client to provide username and password?

I a bit new to SSL. So please let me know the steps to connect to any ssl server using Tera Term.

Another doubt is that can i use a TCP server socket without using http or ftp or telnet session?

Answer (score 0):

There is a general TCP server example in the microchip TCP/IP stack package.

While I don't have experience with SSL and Microchip, I suspect you are confusing several things

- ssl and ssh (or do you use teraterm in tunnel mode?)
- The various protocols for SSL.  TLS is SSH/Lv3, and that is something that underpowered microcontrollers can't do. try to get SSLv1 working first

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the TCP/IP Stack (v5.2b) from Microchip has built in support for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that you need to use a third party SSL library for it work.

Take a look here http://www.yassl.com/yaSSL/cyassl-pic32.html

It will get you started !!

Answer (score 0):

Teraterm supports SSH but not SSL. However you can use TeraTerm by selecting a Telnet connection and using an SSL tunnel to do the handshaking and encrypt/decrypt the data, such as,

https://www.stunnel.org/index.html

Your stunnel.conf file would look something like this,

```
client = yes
sslVersion = SSLv3

[demo]
accept = 127.0.0.1:992
connect = 192.168.1.3:992
```

Where the accept is the IP:port no. that TeraTerm connects to and connect is the IP:port no. of your Microchip SSL server.

This worked for me using the Microchip MLA v2013-06-15.